# simple crontab not running

Tags: bash, cron

I've searched through several forums, but cannot find anything that suggests that my cron job is incorrect. I have a .sh script that runs a python script, and I want my cron job to run that .sh script every minute. I have my email entered, but so far nothing proves that the job is running.

Here is my cronjob:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    MAILTO=name@email.com

    * * * * * /home/somedir/anotherdir/bash_scripts/script.sh
```

The script "script.sh" runs correctly when I run it at the command line. The cron job is currently in the same folder. I have a feeling this is incorrect. Any suggestions? Thank  you!!!

Comment: Cronjob, in the same folder? To add a new cronjob, use `crontab -e` Put your `* * * * * /path/to/your/script.sh` in there, save it, and exit the editor. It will update cron and all will be happy.

Comment: I did enter crontab -e at the command line. Also, when I edit my cron_script and then exit the editor, I run 'crontab /home/kgleeso/bash_scripts/cron_script.sh'. Are these not correct?

Comment: I don't believe there is any need to run `'crontab /home/kgleeso/bash_scripts/cron_script.sh'` after running `crontab -e` I'm not sure what that would do to be honest.

Comment: Okay that's all I'm doing now. It returns no error, and I've triple checked the paths. Is there some sort of error-checking I can do with this?

Comment: The `#!/bin/bash` is unnecessary; cron will treat it as a comment and ignore it. What does `script.sh` do? Try adding a command to `script.sh` that, for example, creates a file in your home directory; that will tell you whether it ran.

Comment: `script.sh` might be running something inside of it that doesn't exist in your path. A `cron` job doesn't run in the same shell as your login shell. It has its own. You might need to set the PATH in the `crontab` file.

Comment: Keith Thompson: The script.sh does indeed create a new file, so I've been checking the folder to see if it's been created, which it has not.   @lurker: Thank you for the suggestion. I never got a great tutorial on PATH. Should I set the actual PATH to /bin/bash? I see on another page that some people set SHELL. I'm not sure how they differ.

Comment: `SHELL` indicates your shell command, specifically. It points to a single command which is your shell (*e.g.*, `SHELL=/bin/bash`). `PATH` is a list of file system paths to tell the shell where to find commands you want to execute (*e.g.*, `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/home/me/bin`). You can Google "PATH bash" for more details. But if you want the system to find the commands you are attempting to execute in `script.sh`, they need to be in your `PATH`, and the default `PATH` may not be adequate. I can't tell you what the `PATH` needs to be because I have no idea what is in your `script.sh` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entry should probably look like this:

```
MAILTO=name@email.com
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

* * * * * /home/somedir/anotherdir/bash_scripts/script.sh
```

...PATH is just a guess. You can replace it with the output you get when running this in your shell:

```
echo $PATH
```

As already explained in comments PATH needs to be set so that the commands run in your script works without their full path.